# convert tuples into lists : extracted url from a database==> came as a tuple

Tags: python, list, sqlite, tuples

So, I extracted some URL from an SQLite database. I thought it would come as a list but apparently, it came as a tuple.

```
c.execute("SELECT url FROM moz_places WHERE (last_visit_date)>='"+yesterday+"'")

mylist_of_url= c.fetchall()

mylist_of_url_splitted= []

for url in mylist_of_url:
  mylist_of_url_splitted.append(url.split('/'))
print(mylist_of_url_splitted)
```

> attributeerror : "tuple" object as no attribute "split"

Do you know how could I convert my tuple into a list?

Comment: You mean like `list(some_tuple)`?

Comment: Did you try `list(url)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, that's the default type of the result of the `.fetchall()` - these are actually not tuples but [`Row` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Row) which mimic the tuples. You could *unpack them in the loop*:

```
for url, in mylist_of_url:
    mylist_of_url_splitted.append(url.split('/'))
```